# How do I get th hover to work on my nav bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am working on my vertical nav bar. The name to that icon is supposed to become visible on the right side. While hovering over the icon the name is also supposed to change color from white to black, and it is not working.

I tried to change the tags around to see if it would help. I also changed the tags in the html and changed the tags in CSS so that tags could work. I looked up on this site to see if I can find a resolution to my problem.
I was not able to get my nav bar to work.

I can't figure out how to put the code in here. I am will to send my code through a message if that can help. I spent over 30minutes trying to figure out how to post the code.

First time using this site.

I have re written the code several times, I reworked the tags, I have looked up tutorials and I have tried getting in contact with web developers and I was not able to fix the problem.

Again I am will to send the code through message, it will be easier for me than to post it here as it its a bit difficult for me.

Comment: [Here is how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/318803) to include code in your question. Don’t post your entire code, though, just the bit you are having trouble with. Better still, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the color change from white to black when hovered and also set to visible, you can just always set it to black by using this

```
    .icon_name {
        visiblity:hidden;
        color:black;
    }
   .icon:hover {
      icon_name {
         visiblity: visible;
      }
   }
```

However if, you want the name to be visible *both* on the right and left side, you can just do the same thing but rename the icon_name to right_icon_name and left icon name.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I was able to fix my problem in a different way.

Also this is my first time posting, I was not able to understand how to post the code properly.

Thank you for your help...

Comment: How did you fix your code

Comment: I am teaching myself web code and I played around with the code. I changed the tag names till I got what I wanted.